# Blender OpenGL animation rendering without open GUI (display) from command line

Tags: opengl, command-line, render, blender

I'd like to render animation with opengl.
I have a script for render and this working with open blender GUI.
I want to run this script (with render.opengl function) from linux command line without X.

I tried some way without success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Can't be done.

Long answer: For OpenGL to be usable you need a so called render context. OpenGL itself can not create render contexts, that's the job of the display graphics system (X11, EGL/Wayland, etc.).

Mesa's software rasterizer is accompanied with an offscreen render context manager, however using that one must be prorammed specifically, works only with Mesa *and Blender doesn't support it!*

When launched in windowless mode, Blender doesn't even bother to create a render context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
export DISPLAY=:0
blender -b your_file.blend -a
```

Not exactly what you asked, but  it will do the trick to if you want to render in a remote machine. 
Basically it is going to create the render context in the remote machine, nevertheless the render command itself won't open a GUI